# Apply FPM on an Ubuntu server - What is the "username" if I use the default "000-default.conf" file?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-server

I am following this tutorial to apply FPM on the server: 
http://blog.koenreiniers.nl/guide-to-combining-apache-virtual-hosts-and-php7-fpm/

I am new to working with servers in this level.

What is the "username" in this case? "root" ?

These are my current settings in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
    ServerAdmin myname@potato.pro
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0):

The user of PHP-FPM  should be identical to the user the Apache VHost runs under. You can set the Apache VHost user manually with the directive `VHostUser`. If you leave your VHost like this, the default user is used (`www-data` for Ubuntu).

For security reasons, you shouldn't run PHP-FPM or the Apache VHosts as root.

Comment: It's a local LAMP and not a prod, so it should be fine I guess (?) in terms of security.

Comment: I'd still advise to set it to `www-data` (in the PHP-FPM config, Apache VHost config doesn't need to be modified). The security risks aren't very high in a local dev environment, of course. But I'd get in the habit of not running these services as root.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into this. Just to make things clear in my head - I should research for how to create a host user and how to create a user on ubuntu, and then allow permissions for the user to enter this specific hostname?

Comment: The user `www-data` gets created when you install Apache, so you don't have to create it manually. The user only needs access to your PHP files (possible via `chown` / `chmod`).